# Combine emails from multiple people into one email per week

Tags: email, gmail

I'm in med school right now and our administrators love sending us over a dozen emails per week. It's pretty infuriating clicking through all of them.

I'm wondering if it would be possible to just combine all these emails into a single email per week so that I don't miss anything, but I'm also not overwhelmed.

edit: or even anything I could use to send auto replies to messages that are too long?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried setting up a filter to capture these emails and put them away into a folder that doesn't clutter your main inbox?

Comment: I know I could do that but it wouldn't solve the problem of still having to click through every email

Comment: Sounds like a basic email digest, try googling how to set up one of those with gmail. I'm not sure if gmail can do it directly, but perhaps with another tool / site you could forward all the messages to a special account you set up, and have them sent back to you all together once a week